# add a key to contour plot using ks package

Tags: r, key, contour, kernel-density

I've been tinkering around with the ks package and I'm trying to add a key to a contour plot.

I have been able to produce a contour plot + key using display="filled.contour"

```
fhat <- kde(x,w)

plot(fhat, display="filled.contour",col =terrain.colors(20, alpha = 0.95),cont=seq(5,95,by=10))
```

the problem with using this, is that the colors are set to a default palette and my col attribute doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I used the "filled.contour2" display option to get the colours right but the key disapears

```
plot(fhat, display="filled.contour2",col =terrain.colors(20, alpha = 0.95),cont=seq(5,95,by=10))
```

Would anyone have a solution to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Call `filled.contour` with the proper arguments?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I should have looked harder. correct code is :  
plot(fhat, display="filled.contour",color.palette=terrain.colors,cont=seq(5,95,by=10)